# What is kcatcode in pTeX and upTeX?

Tags: tex-core, japanese, ptex

The Japanese TeX engines pTeX and upTeX treat separately Latin and Japanese characters, in a way I don't fully understand.  They introduce a notion of kcatcode of a Japanese character, which takes values 16, 17, 18 (in pTeX) or 19 (in upTeX) *EDIT: also 15 as described in the answer below*.  What do these values correspond to?  The `\meaning` of a character with these different `\kcatcode` values is the same: the following shows `> kanji character 本.` four times (and an error in pTeX since 19 is not allowed).

```
\kcatcode`本=16
\show 本
\kcatcode`本=17
\show 本
\kcatcode`本=18
\show 本
\kcatcode`本=19
\show 本
```

In addition, the kcatcode values 16,17,19 seem to be allowed in control sequences.

Comment: hm `texdoc ptex-guide-en` implies the 16-19 kcatcodes exist but not what they mean

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Basics of `\kcatcode`

In pTeX/upTeX, all Japanese characters are classified into some pre-defined groups [*1], and each of these groups is given a `\kcatcode` value.
The value works as a marker which means that the character is treated as a Japanese character token.
It is also referred to by pTeX/upTeX in various situations, including the input processor and the line breaking routine.

#### Meanings of `\kcatcode` value

Here are the meanings of `\kcatcode` values ​​in pTeX/upTeX:

- 16: Kanji characters (e.g. 漢 日 ...)
- 17: Kana (Hiragana, Katakana) characters (e.g. あ ア)
- 18: Symbols (e.g. 、 。)
- 19: Hangul characters (e.g. 아 하) -- this is only available in upTeX

In upTeX, a special `\kcatcode` value 15 is also allowed; it means that the character is *not* interpreted as a Japanese character token, and a normal `\catcode` value becomes effective.
This feature is meant for compatibility with Western TeX, including UTF-8 handling of the inputenc package (see also "6.6.2 Detecting upTeX" in ptex-guide-en.pdf).

The characters which have kcatcode 16,17,19 are allowed in control sequences (similar to catcode 11). The characters which have kcatcode 18 are allowed in control symbols (similar to catcode 12).
Regardless of all of these, the result of `\meaning` for any Japanese character will always look like `kanji character <something>`.

---

Note:

[*1] Unlike `\catcode`, the `\kcatcode` settings are effective *not* for individual characters, but for some pre-defined block of characters. (e.g. both "あ" and "い" are Hiragana characters, so they share the same `\kcatcode` value.)
Also, the classification is a bit different between pTeX and upTeX (pTeX: based on JIS ku-ten codes, upTeX: based on Unicode blocks), which is hardwired in the WEB source.

---

See also: H. Kitagawa, "Distinguishing 8-bit characters and Japanese characters in (u)pTeX" (TUGboat 41:3, 2020) https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents41-3.html --- The mentioned "experimental version of (u)pTeX" is not merged yet.

See also: T. Tanaka, "upTeX --- Unicode version of pTeX with CJK extensions" (TUGboat 34:3, 2013) https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents34-3.html

Comment: Nice answer.  It sounds like you are saying these are more like character codes than catcodes?  It also sounds like a character's `\kcatcode` is not meant to be redefined.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No `\kcatcode` is more like `\catcode` as it defines "how to interpret/handle a character". There are only few cases that `\kcatcode` needs to be changed (someone might change `\kcatcode` in order to allow Japanese symbols into control sequences, but it might break some aspects of Japanese-specific line breaking routine).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Thanks for these details.  In the TUGboat article you cite, it is explained (section 2.2) that the kcatcode is not stored in the token, but if I replace `\show 本` by `\let\A=本`, then `\let\B=本` and so on, then compare `\A`, `\B`, etc with `\ifx` I see that I can get kanji character tokens with the same character code but different kcatcode.  Is the TUGboat article wrong in this respect?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The behavior in \let-equal JP char token is still under discussion, sorry. (see https://github.com/texjporg/ptex-manual/issues/4 for detail; currently \ifcat and \ifx are inconsistent in pTeX)

Comment: Regarding the behavior in \let-equal JP char token: as mentioned in the TUGboat article, pTeX does not fully support changing `\kcatcode` in the middle of document. OTOH, upTeX fully supports changing `\kcatcode` anywhere by safely storing `\kcatcode` value into the token.

Comment: Thank you @HironobuYAMASHITA, I will have to think of how to best support that in l3regex and other places in expl3.