# upLaTeX get Japanese quotation mark indentation with utbook.cls

Tags: punctuation, japanese, uplatex

[image: With utbook class]

The `utbook.cls` gives full-width quotation mark align at the beginning of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{utbook}
\usepackage{pxrubrica}
\rubysetup{<->}
\begin{document}
男は店主とは顔馴染みらしく、あれこれにこやかに言葉を交わし、ひとたび器へ向かうや、
ナイアガラ\ruby[j]{瀑布}{ばく|ふ}が逆流するような迫力で\ruby[m]{麺}{めん}をすすっ
た。そうして私が食い終わるよりも前にスープを飲み干した。まさに神業であった。

男はラーメンを食べ終わったあと、私をじろじろと眺めた。やがて「貴君」と、ひどく古
風な言葉で呼びかけてきた。

「下鴨幽水荘の人だろう」

私が\ruby[m]{頷}{うなず}くと、男は満足気に笑った。

「私も下鴨幽水荘に住んでいる。よろしく」

「どうも」
\end{document}
```

However other more up to date class such as `jlreq.cls` can give half width quotation marks at beginning of the line.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,tate]{jlreq}
```

[image: with jlreq class]

How can I get this effect while keeping most of the setting of `utbook.cls`?

It isn't that the virtual font used by `utbook` doesn't support half width quotation mark compression, because if add `\noindent` to the line `「下鴨幽水荘の人だろう」`:

[image: showing half width quotation mark]

<s>However I have no clause on where to config the extended amount of indentation for quotation marks at the beginning of paragraph.</s>

I find this line from pTeX manual,

> 実際，開き括弧の前・閉じ括弧(全角コンマを含む)の後には JFM グルーが入っているので半角しかない.

(Before/after the brackets (including quotation marks), there is a half space glue inserted.)

And the `\inhibitglue` primitive from pTeX can fix it.

So, currently I'm manually adding a command `\fixquote` before any paragraphs starting with `「`, which is defined as:

```
\def\fixquote{\strut\inhibitglue}
```

used as like `\fixquote「下鴨幽水荘の人だろう」`.

Is it possible to automatically handle this? Maybe via catcode? I haven't yet figured out how catcode works specifically in (u)pTeX, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically handle this, using the `bxjaprnind` package will be easy.

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{utbook}
\usepackage{bxjaprnind}%% add this!
\usepackage{pxrubrica}
\rubysetup{<->}
\begin{document}
男は店主とは顔馴染みらしく、あれこれにこやかに言葉を交わし、ひとたび器へ向かうや、
ナイアガラ\ruby[j]{瀑布}{ばく|ふ}が逆流するような迫力で\ruby[m]{麺}{めん}をすすっ
た。そうして私が食い終わるよりも前にスープを飲み干した。まさに神業であった。

男はラーメンを食べ終わったあと、私をじろじろと眺めた。やがて「貴君」と、ひどく古
風な言葉で呼びかけてきた。

「下鴨幽水荘の人だろう」

私が\ruby[m]{頷}{うなず}くと、男は満足気に笑った。

「私も下鴨幽水荘に住んでいる。よろしく」

「どうも」
\end{document}
```

For more detail, please refer to [its documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bxjaprnind) (though in Japanese).

> I haven't yet figured out how catcode works specifically in (u)pTeX, any hints?

Please refer to [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598337/what-is-kcatcode-in-ptex-and-uptex). The (k)catcode only classifies how to interpret the token (e.g. symbols cannot be used as part of control word), and it does not relate to font metrics.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed solve my problem! I mentioned catcode because I thought I could define UTF-8 characters as TeX macro, but it seems impossible with upTeX.

Comment: @LdBeth The CJK characters (default catcode 16 or higher) are not allowed to make active (13), as their catcode is a marker that defines it as a CJK character.